# Combining and communicating between multiple virutual environments

Tags: python, dependencies, virtualenv

Suppose I want to use two functions that require two different versions of the same library in Python. If I need sequential use of the two functions, I could define two virtual environments and activate and deactivate the virtual environments from my ".py" script using os. But what should I do if I want to combine the two functions in same code block ? Or simply if I need the two functions to run in parallel while being called from the same script ?

(I am new with virtual environments and related issues.)

Comment: You need to resolve the dependency mismatch somehow, maybe by upgrading or downgrading one of the libraries involved.  A virtual environment can only have one version of a given library installed.

Comment: What if I manage to separate the .py script containing the two fonctions into two .py scripts. Is it possible to run each script within one virtual environnement and somehow communicate between the two programs ? Is there some structured way how to do this ?

Comment: It would be possible to use the `subprocess` module to invoke one from the other, but they'd be two separate programs and couldn't do things like share variables.  You'd have to define some format for one program to pass input to another, either over stdin/stdout or using files.

Comment: I see, thanks. I am reading about possibilities of combining or connecting two Docker containers within the same project. Since in my (limited) understanding Docker and virtual environments are two different tools to resolve almost the same kind of issues, why aren't there methods for combining virtual environments similar to those for Docker containers ? (just for my understanding)